# multiprocessing in stoppable multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to use multiprocessing after multithreading. And i need to stop all the routines with the command given outside of the new thread. Following code has a working example to stop a thread with using thread attribute as stop flag. However, it seems using thread attributes are not working when it combined with multiprocessing.

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

def bar(param):
    current_thread = threading.currentThread()
    print("Current thread: ", current_thread)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if getattr(current_thread, "do_run", True):
        print("value:", param)
        bar(param+1)
    else:
        print("Stop")
        return param
        
def foo():
    #without multiprocessing
    bar(10)
    
def foo2():
    #with multi processing
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(10,))
    p.start()
    p.join() 

    

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    newThread = threading.Thread(target=foo)
    newThread.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    newThread.do_run = False
    
    newThread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2)
    newThread2.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    newThread2.do_run = False
```

Output:

```
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 10
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 11
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 12
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 13
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 14
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
value: 15
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 6004)>
Stop
Current thread:  <_MainThread(MainThread, started 4624)>
value: 10
Current thread:  <_MainThread(MainThread, started 4624)>
value: 11
.
.
.
#does not stop
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what behaviour you expect. Processes aren't Threads. The entire point is that they don't behave the same. Are you just asking how to gracefully stop a process?

Comment: When you call `p.join()` in `foo2()` that thread in the main process blocks until the subprocess finishes. However processes run in a separate memory-space, so the threads of the main process aren't visible in the subprocess.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, but how to stop a process if i did not start directly. i started it indirectly, via a new thread.

Comment: @martineau then, how to access the process properly to stop it

Comment: Well, `thread2` in the main process is blocked because of the `join()`. If `p` wasn't a local variable (i.e. was a global or the attribute of some global class instance), then some other thread in the main process that isn't blocked (including its main thread) might be able to call `p.terminate()`.

Comment: @martineau I posted your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Should I take that to mean it worked? `;¬)`

Comment: @martineau yes it worked thank you again : ) but it seems i need to pass lots of variable about processes to lots of files. i wish i could handle this process hell better.

Comment: That's good to hear…you're welcome. Am not sure what you mean about "lots of variable about processes to lots of files", but whenever you find yourself writing a lot of repetitious code, it's often an indication that there's probably a better way to be doing things. This is embodied in the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new process with `p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(10,))`, that process has its own main thread on which `bar` will be running which is not the same thread on which the main process's main thread is setting "do_run" to `False`. This is the crux of your problem.

The simplest fix is to pass to `bar` either a `threading.Event` instance or `multiprocessing.Event` instance depending on whether it is running in another thread of the main process or another thread of a sub-process. It should then stop whenever that event has been "set." I would also modify `bar` to replace its tail recursion by a `while` loop and combine `print` statements for clarity:

```py
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

def bar(param, event):
    while True:
        current_thread = threading.currentThread()
        print("Current thread: ", current_thread, end = ' ')
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if not event.is_set():
            print("value:", param, flush=True)
            param += 1
        else:
            print("Stop", flush=True)
            return param

def foo(event):
    #without multiprocessing
    bar(10, event)

def foo2(event):
    #with multi processing
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(10, event))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    event.set()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event1 = threading.Event()
    newThread = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(event1,))
    newThread.start()

    event2 = multiprocessing.Event()
    newThread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2, args=(event2,))
    newThread2.start()

    # for the "without multiprocessing" case:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    event1.set()

    newThread.join()
    newThread2.join()
```

Prints:

```
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 10
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 11
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 12
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 13
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 14
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 15
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 16
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 17
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 18
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> value: 19
Current thread:  <Thread(Thread-1, started 31712)> Stop
Current thread:  <_MainThread(MainThread, started 25948)> value: 10
Current thread:  <_MainThread(MainThread, started 25948)> Stop
```

Comment: Thanks for the better solution. This is what i want exactly. But, I just edited your code a bit to stop thread from main not from foo2 function.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that uses the advice from @martineau

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

def bar(param):
    current_thread = threading.currentThread()
    print("Current thread: ", current_thread)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    if getattr(current_thread, "do_run", True):
        print("value:", param)
        bar(param+1)
    else:
        print("Stop")
        return param
        
def foo2():
    #with multi processing
    global p
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(10,))
    p.start()
    p.join() 

    

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    global p

    newThread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2)
    newThread2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    p.terminate()
```

This is the edited solution of @Booboo

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

def bar(param, event):
    while True:
        current_thread = threading.currentThread()
        print("Current thread: ", current_thread, end = ' ')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if not event.is_set():
            print("value:", param, flush=True)
            param += 1
        else:
            print("Stop", flush=True)
            return param

def foo2(event):
    #with multi processing
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=bar, args=(10, event))
    p.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    event2 = multiprocessing.Event()
    newThread2 = threading.Thread(target=foo2, args=(event2,))
    newThread2.start()

    time.sleep(1)
    event2.set()

    newThread2.join()
```