# How to kill a Process in the middle of execution after using join()?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to kill a certain process or all processes in the middle of its execution. My sample code is as follows. How can I do that? Here, I want to kill the processes based on the current time. If the time is divisible by 2, I want to kill the processes, otherwise not.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def runTests(a, b):
    time.sleep(10)
    return a + b


def main(kill_processes):
    print(kill_processes)
    processes = []

    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        proc = Process(target=runTests, args=(2, 4,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
        if kill_processes:
            print("killing")
            proc.terminate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if round(time.time()) % 2 == 0:
        main(True)
    else:
        main(False)
```

Comment: See [multiprocessing in stoppable multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731846/multiprocessing-in-stoppable-multithreading) — i.e. Use threading.

Comment: You can use `proc.terminate()` to kill a process but I dont entarily understand what you want to achieve. After `join()` the process just finished so there is no need to terminate it.

Comment: What is your criteria for terminating the process? proc.terminate and proc.kill will do the job. proc.join has a timeout parameter if the goal is to terminate after X seconds.

Comment: @blazej, I need to terminate before the processes end. In this example, they just end, I need to terminate it before it happens upon some condition. I can put that condition later

Comment: @ArunDesiraju - but that's part of the issue. Is there some other thread? It could run through `processes` and terminate them. Is it a signal from an external source?

Comment: @martineau I have provided MWE, based on time, it could decide to kill or not to kill the processes

Comment: OK, that should help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multiprocessing.Event](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event) to signal termination condition to your child processes. Don't join child processes in the main process. Instead let main process and child processes run in their own loop. Check the termination condition in the main loop, and signal it using the `multiprocessing.Event` to the child processes.

The `Event` object is passed as an argument to child process. Child process continuously checks if the event is set, and stops its work if so. Main loop checks the termination condition and sets the `Event` if condition is met (in the below example main loop waits for `Ctrl+c`).

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
import time


def do_work(a, b, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            print(f"worker {os.getpid()}: working ...", a + b)
            a += 1
            b += 1
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print(f"worker {os.getpid()}: received SIGINT. ignore.")
            pass

    print(f"worker {os.getpid()}: stop_event is set. exit.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    stop_event = mp.Event()
    procs = []
    for i in range(3):
        # p = mp.Process(target=do_work, args=(1, 2, stop_event), daemon=True)
        p = mp.Process(target=do_work, args=(1, 2, stop_event))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    while True:
        try:
            print("main: waiting for termination signal")
            time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("main: received termination signal")            
            stop_event.set()
            
            # wait for the processes to stop
            for p in procs:
                p.join()

            for p in procs:
                print(f"worker {p.pid} is terminated: {not p.is_alive()}")
            
            # exit the main loop
            break
    
    print("main: bye")
```

Comment: Thanks @zardosht. I like this way. Instead of looking for KeyboardInterrupt that will terminate all processes, how can I selectively kill processes based on pid? I need this script to pass pid of each process to a different program, and have that program pass in the pid that it would kill. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have used 'psutil' to list all the running processes, but there is no way to know which pid belongs to which process of the three.

Comment: @ades I think this is another question. The KeyboardInterrupt above is just an example for a termination condition (as you see, I ignore it in the worker). Generally, I wouldn't rely on signals, or even `Process.terminate()` for killing a process. I would instead think of a way how I can gracefully stop the worker (e.g. by stopping a loop and returning from the worker function), when the `Event` is set.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates how to do it by using multiple threads in a manner similar to what's in the answer to the question [multiprocessing in stoppable multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731846/multiprocessing-in-stoppable-multithreading) that I suggested you have a look at.

Basically all that is going on is all the `join()` calls are done in separate threads, so they won't block the main thread in the main process — which makes it possible for it to kill them.

```
import threading
import time
from multiprocessing import Process


def runTests(a, b):
    time.sleep(10)
    return a + b

def create_process(lock, i):
    proc = Process(target=runTests, args=(2, 4,))
    print(f'{proc.name} created')
    proc.start()
    with lock:
        processes.append(proc)
    proc.join()


def main(kill_processes):
    global processes
    N = 3
    lock = threading.RLock()
    processes = []

    print(f'main({kill_processes=})')

    for i in range(N):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=create_process, args=(lock, i))
        thread.start()

    while True:  # Wait for all processes to have been created.
        with lock:
            if len(processes) == N:
                break
            else:
                time.sleep(.001)

    if kill_processes:
        print("Killing the processes")
        for proc in processes:
            proc.terminate()
            print(f'process {proc} terminated')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(True)

#    if round(time.time()) % 2 == 0:
#        main(True)
#    else:
#        main(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to terminate based on time, use the `timeout` paramter of `join`.  One way is to set a stop time and as each process is joined, use time remaining as its timeout.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

def runTests(a, b):
    time.sleep(10)
    return a + b

def main(kill_processes):
    print(kill_processes)
    processes = []

    end = time.time() + 10 # wait 10 seconds

    for i in range(3):
        print(i)
        proc = Process(target=runTests, args=(2, 4,))
        processes.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in processes:
        if kill_processes:
            delta = end - time.time()
        else:
            delta = None
        proc.join(delta)
        if kill_processes:
            print("killing")
            proc.terminate()
            proc.join(1)
            if proc.is_alive():
                proc.kill()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if round(time.time()) % 2 == 0:
        main(True)
    else:
        main(False)
```